# Android studio 1.3 searching source only from search.maven.org

Tags: java, android

I have a 3rd jar from my local repo. (My company has a local nexus.)
Some jars are from this local repo.

When I need to download the source, Android studio only searching  search.maven.org and  oss.sonatype.org. 
Of course, there do not my 3rd jar source.

I want to kown, is there a setting to set the source searching url, such as http://repo.myCompanyLocalRepo.com ?
Any ideas will be appreciated.

My searching like this (only from this two site):
[image]
[image]

Comment: try like repositories {
    maven { url 'urs URL' }
}

Comment: tried. This method only add dependency(jar) search scope, not for source search.